# Testing without loading Rails: faked class need so be 'unfaked' after tests run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've refactored part of my test suite to not load rails when performing tests.  The code below is an example of a test file that loads only selection pieces of Rails.  It also fakes the "project" class.  My problem is that this faked project class ends up overriding the normal project class and all other tests that involve the project class now fail.

How do I un-override my project class after this test file runs?

```
require 'active_model'
require 'active_model/validations'
require 'active_record/callbacks'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
class Project
  include ActiveModel::Validations    
  include ActiveRecord::Callbacks
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @general_media = attributes[:general_media]
  end
  attr_accessor :general_media
end

require_relative '../../../app/models/project/media.rb'
```

UPDATE:  I think this comes close to what I need, except that I'm getting an error about Project being an uninitialized constant.  I must be instantiating this test class incorrectly.

```
require 'active_model'
require 'active_model/validations'
require 'active_record/callbacks'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string' #used for '.blank?' method

require_relative '../../../app/models/project/media.rb'

describe Project::Media do
  before(:all) do 

    class Project
      include ActiveModel::Validations    
      include ActiveRecord::Callbacks
      def initialize(attributes = {})
        @general_media = attributes[:general_media]
      end
      attr_accessor :general_media
    end

  end

  after(:all) { Object.send(:remove_const, :Project) }

  #then all the tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to un-define a class with [`Module#remove_const`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-remove_const).

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :Project)
```

Its a private method so you'll need to use `send` rather than a regular method call.

UPDATE:

Perhaps try the following:

```
require 'active_model'
require 'active_model/validations'
require 'active_record/callbacks'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string' #used for '.blank?' method

class Project
  include ActiveModel::Validations    
  include ActiveRecord::Callbacks
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @general_media = attributes[:general_media]
  end
  attr_accessor :general_media
end

require_relative '../../../app/models/project/media.rb'

describe Project::Media do

  after(:all) { Object.send(:remove_const, :Project) }

  ...
```

You will need to declare the Project class before the describe block if the subject depends on it. Also assuming your `Media` model depends on it before you require that.

Later tests for the Project class will need to reload it, assuming they are separate tests you can just `require` your project model class in that test file if you want a minimal (fast) test, or via the normal spec_helper if you want to load the whole Rails application (slow).

As discussed in comments it might be easier to simply stub out the Project class rather than redefine it.

Comment: I think this is what looking for, but I'm not sure how to implement it.  I tried to add this after the `describe Project::Media do` block:
  `after(:all) { Object.send(:remove_const, :Project) }`.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just noticed typo in my comment above and it's too late to edit it.  It should say `after(:all) { Project::Media.send(:remove_const, :Project) }`

Comment: Yes an `after(:all)` block would be the place to do this kind of thing but this would need to be inside the `describe` block.

Comment: Yeah, that totally worked.  I guess it's obvious that it'd have to be inside that block, now that I think about it.  Thanks.

Comment: Inside the same describe block it makes sense to declare the test Project class in a `before(:all)` block.

Comment: One small issue: 'remove_const' doesn't help do the un-unverriding I need it to do.  I don't just need to remove the constant, I need the old constant back.  I guess that'd mean stubbing the whole class...

Comment: I just added an update to the post.  I'm having trouble declaring that test Projet class correctly.

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing exactly what you are trying to test. In general if you are looking to isolate one model from another in a test it makes sense to just stub the 'other' model class, that would certainly be a lot simpler. I assumed your 'real' Project class was not defined in the context of this particular test and would later be loaded in the tests that do need it, but if you do remove and const there is nothing to stop you redefining it with the real implementation.

Comment: In your latest edit the problem looks to me that your describe subject (`Project::Media`) refers to the `Project` class before the `before(:all)` has chance to define it. If you declare `Project` outside the `describe` block it would probably be fine, though less tidy.

Comment: Ahh, yes, of course, I just need to redefine the Project class using it's original project.rb.  I suppose I'd just add that to the 'after' block.  How how would I implement that?  Would I just load the model file?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and all the work you did helping me understand what I needed to do.